# Cache API responses until told to release?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, caching

I have the following model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def stripe_plan_id
    self.stripe_subscription.plan.id
  end

  def stripe_subscription
    customer = Stripe::Customer.retrieve(self.stripe_customer_id)
    customer.subscriptions.retrieve(self.stripe_subscription_id)
  end
end
```

I've got the model attribute `stripe_plan_id` I don't want to it persist in the database using ActiveRecord, but I need to check this parameter a lot. I would like to cache it on my server, and flush it on demand. Ideally I don't want to use redis.

What's the best approach? I'm trying to work out if `||=` can be used somehow.

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of ways, i'm assuming you know how to cache already using whatever you have (memcached, redis, rails.cache, etc), let me know if that is not the case.  I recommend creating a caching class that gets or reloads cache based on an id.  Your memoizing wouldn't work for your case because you want to persist between controllers.

```
def StripeCache < Struct.new(:user)

  def cache_key
    "#{user.id}_stripe_plan_id"
  end 

  def get
    ReadFromCache(cache_key)
  end

  def reload
    WriteToCache(cache_key, user.stripe_plan_id)
  end
end
```

Then when you want to get this you just call

```
StripeCache.new(user).get
```

and to save new stuff you call

```
StripeCache.new(user).reload
```

Is a little extra overhead, but will abstract all the reading and writing to and from cache from you.